# Query Email Template folder parent Id - is it possible?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, email-template, folder, sobject-tree

I'm trying to implement a lightning-component-based custom display of email templates and their folders in a form similar to lightning:tree (a tree view with collapsible levels).

There's a nested folders structure:

- -> Folder level 1
- --> Folder level 2
- ---> Folder level 3 {
- email template 1,
- email template 2,
- ...
  }

Every folder can contain another folder and/or Lightning Email Templates.

Now I want to query Email Templates with information in which folder it's stored.

This one is easy: `[SELECT Id, Name, FolderId FROM EmailTempate... etc].`

**The problem is that I need to know not only the direct Folder Id/Name in which the template is stored, but also parent, grandparent and so on.** Even if you start from [SELECT Id, Name FROM Folder... etc] you're not able to get parent Id.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Mateusz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can get parentId of the Folder just like this:
`SELECT ParentId FROM Folder`

Here is the code you need to execute to retrieve all folders where email templates are stored:

```
List<EmailTemplate> templates = [SELECT Id, Name, FolderId FROM EmailTemplate];
Set<Id> foldersIdsToCheck = new Set<Id>();
for (EmailTemplate template_i : templates) {
    foldersIdsToCheck.add(template_i.FolderId);
}

Set<Id> foundFoldersIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Folder> foundFolders = new List<Folder>();

while (foldersIdsToCheck.size() > 0) { //retrieving parent folders until they exist
    List<Folder> folders = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Folder WHERE Id IN :foldersIdsToCheck];
    foldersIdsToCheck.clear();
    for (Folder folder_i : folders) {
        if (folder_i.ParentId != null) {
            foldersIdsToCheck.add(folder_i.ParentId);
        }

        if (!foundFoldersIds.contains(folder_i.Id)) {//store found folders to list to easily build tree when all are retrived
            foundFoldersIds.add(folder_i.Id);
            foundFolders.add(folder_i);
        }
    }
}

//TODO: build the tree with email templates and related folders
```